# Why is temperature of a system an intensive property whereas internal energy is not?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

As far as I understand, temperature is a function of internal energy. Internal energy depends on the mass but temperature does not. I don't understand how these two match up.

I clearly understand that if I consider a room to be a system and split it in two equal halves, the internal energy of the two systems are split equally, and the volume is halved, so these two are extensive, but temperature and pressure do not change, so these are intensive.

Yet we know that temperature and internal energy are related, if one is halved the other should change as well. Please help me to understand what's going on.

Comment: For the ideal gas, the internal energy and the temperature are related as $U=\frac{3}{2} Nk_BT$ which tells you that $U$ is proportional to the number of particles $N$ i.e., extensive. To understand why temperature is intensive consider the following. Consider a gas in a box at temperature $T$. Now insert a diathermic partition in the middle of the box. The number of particles in each of the partitions will be halved. But will the temperature change?

Comment: I do understand that but as I stated earlier that U is f(T), if U changes T should change as well but it does not. My confusion is why does it not change. I think I understand somehow by Mr Oman's answer

Comment: A change in U will give rise to a change in T provided N is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature is a measure of the *average* internal energy of a collection of particles. Since calculating by the average involves dividing by the number of particles, you end up with something like:

$$T\propto\frac{\frac{1}{2}U}{\frac{1}{2}N}$$

Comment: user 39814   see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html

Comment: Where did you get the factors of $1/2$ from? @KyleOman

Comment: @srsThe OP mentions splitting a room into two equal halves.